# How to launch corutines in spring applications

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have an app that consumes some messages from a message Queue and processes them. The processing is implemented as suspending functions and there is a service that will publish the events to a `Channel<Event>`, I have another service that will basically do:

```
for (event in channel) {
   eventProcessor.process(event)
}
```

The problem is that this is also a suspending function, and I am really not sure what's the proper way to launch it within the context of Spring.

My initial solution was to do the following:

```
@Bean
fun myProcessor(eventProcessor: EventProcessor, channel: Channel<Event>): Job {
GlobalScope.launch {
  eventProcessor.startProcessing(channel)
}
}
```

But it seems somehow hacky, and I am not sure what's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching anything on a `GlobalScope` is a really bad idea. You loose all advantages of structured concurrency this way.

Instead, make your `EventProcessor` implement `CoroutineScope`.

This will force you to specify `coroutineContext`, so you can use `Dispatchers.Default`:

```
override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default
```

So, the full example will look something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SpringKotlinCoroutinesApplication {
    @Bean
    fun myProcessor(eventProcessor: EventProcessor, channel: Channel<Event>): Job {
        return eventProcessor.startProcessing(channel)
    }

    @Bean
    fun p() = EventProcessor()

    @Bean
    fun c() = Channel<Event>()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringKotlinCoroutinesApplication>(*args)
}

class Event

class EventProcessor : CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default

    fun startProcessing(channel: Channel<Event>) = launch {
        for (e in channel) {
            println(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense, but unless i miss something still does not answer the question about how should i launch it in spring.

Comment: Updated with full example.

Comment: Ok I see your point, but this means that Job should be exposed to the Spring context as a bean? Who is then responsible for cancelling the tasks on shutdown?

Comment: Ideally, `EventProcessor` should be a Bean. And since it extends `CoroutineScope`, it will cancel its tasks. But in your example you're using `myProcessor()`, which is quite redundant.